# Storing the name of an int variable in a String

Tags: java, string, variables, int

Is it possible to store the name of an `int` variable in a string and use that string as a parameter to update the `int`?

Comment: Are you looking for [`Reflection API`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html)

Comment: You probably don't want to do this in the first place

Comment: I'm new to programming. I created an int variable per images that i have and i would like to increment the int for the image that was selected with a click of a button. Basically i'm trying to implement a LIKE counter per images (clicking a LIKE button). I think if i implement the counter and onclick method within the switch case statement this solves my problem but i would like to simplify the code by separating the onclick and counter button outside the switch case statement. But im having difficulty connecting the LIKE button to the selected image INT. Hope this make sense

Comment: So thinking to store the int variable temporarily to string might solve my problem.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is called [reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html).

You are interested in the [Field](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html) class.

**Example:**

```
static class A { 
    public int x = 0;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    A a = new A();
    Field f = A.class.getField("x");
    f.set(a, 5);
    System.out.println(a.x);
}
```

Note that though it is possible - it is not advised to use reflection except for rare cases, it has some major draw backs (maintainability, safety, performance...) - which makes the alternatives *usually* better choices.

Comment: I'm new to programming.  I created an int variable per images that i have and i would like to increment the int for the image that was selected with a click of a button. Basically i'm trying to implement a LIKE counter per images (clicking a LIKE button). I think if i implement the counter and onclick method within the switch case statement this solves my problem but i would like to simplify the code by separating the onclick and counter button outside the switch case statement. But im having difficulty connecting the LIKE button to the selected image INT. Hope this make sense.

Comment: So thinking to store the int variable temporarily to string might solve my problem.

Answer (score 3):

Using reflection in this case would be overkill. You can obtain the intended behavior by simply using a `Map`:

```
Map<String, Integer> variables = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

Then the keys to the map will be the variable names, and the values the actual values:

```
variables.put("var1", 10);
variables.put("var2", 20);
```

Later on, you'll retrieve the values like this:

```
Integer n1 = variables.get("var1"); // n1 == 10
Integer n2 = variables.get("var2"); // n2 == 20
```

And if you need to update the values:

```
variables.put("var1", variables.get("var1") + 32);
Integer n3 = variables.get("var1"); // n3 == 42
```

Answer (score 2):

The context of your question is not clear - a `Map<String, Integer>` might do what you need:

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer> ();
map.put("int1", 1);
map.put("int2", 2);

//now retrieve the ints based on their name
int int1 = map.get("int1");
```